# How does writing a bit to a GPIO pin turn on my induction motor?

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi, physics

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 hooked up to a Yahboom 4wd robot controller board: [image: controller board]

When I set GPIO PIN 2 to output mode, then write a 1 to it, the fan turns on. What actually happens, physically, that turns on the fan motor? I only know software/math, and basic physics, but never studied electrical engineering.

Comment: this may help to get you started ... https://youtu.be/7ukDKVHnac4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without some type of schematic for the controller board, but what's probably happening on a base level is that the motor is connected to some type of transistor that controls when the fan turns on or off.

A transistor is a semiconductor device that acts like a switch. How much voltage and current you need in order to make the transistor conduct (turn on) depends on the actual transistor. For general use, there are BJT's and MOSFETs. BJT's rely on a set amount of current to turn on, and MOSFETs rely on a set voltage to turn on.

There also exist driver IC's that have something that is called an enable pin. It's just want is sounds like: a pin that enables the IC and allows it to operate. It is possible that the fan is connected to a driver IC with the Rasberry Pi setting the enable pin HIGH when you want to use the motor. These IC's also use transistors to operate, but on a more complicated level since their meant for a specific application.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU is nothing more than a piece of silicon with a lot of transistors. How they are connected together makes it a CPU that can execute software. So the software that runs on the CPU can control the transistors that can control the GPIO pin voltage when it is set to be an output.

Logic 0 will set the output pin voltage low to 0V, and logic 1 will set the output pin voltage high to 3.3V supply voltage.

When the voltage is 0V, the pin can sink few milliamps of current, and when voltage is 3.3V, the pin can source few milliamps of current.

The voltage that is on the pin and/or the current it can sink or source can be used to control devices, like larger external transistor to be on or off, that can in turn control large voltages and currents to be on or off, so it can turn the motor on or off.